# Firebird Architecture

Tags: firebird

1. How can I tell which architecture is installed/configured/running on an existing installation of Firebird RDBMS server (ie. Classic Server or Super-Server)?
2. How can I switch between the two modes?
3. Which versions (1.5, 2.0, 2.1) and architectures (CS or SS) of Firebird can be used on multi-processor servers? and how to configure them properly for multi-processor sever and multi-threaded application?

Comment: re Q1: look for fbserver.exe (and potentially fbguardian.exe) on Super-Server installations and look for fb_inet_server.exe on Classic Server installation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 -- To tell which architecture is running open Task Manager and look at running processes. fb_inet_server.exe stands for classic architecture, and fbserver.exe -- super server.

2 -- Close all client connections. Got to Firebird\Bin directory. Execute specified sequence of commands:

```
instsvc stop
instsvc remove
```

then either:

```
instsvc install -s -a   -- for Super Server
```

or

```
instsvc install -c -a   -- for Classic
```

after that:

```
instsvc start
```

3 -- Super Server always runs on single processor or core and can not scale. Use Classic architecture in SMP environment. In latter case dont specify page buffers more than 800-1000.

Be aware that performance of Classic Server depends on performance of disk subsystem. 
For big databases use RAID controllers with internal cache memory, battery and "write back" mode enabled.

Comment: thanks Andrei - any documentation regarding configuring Firebird to use multiple cpu's or is it automatically detected? Is it all in firebird.conf? Will Classic Server support a multi-threaded application too? spasiba.

Comment: in addition to 3 you can look this http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg2-classic-or-super.html

Comment: 2 Sam:

Nope. There is no autodetection envolved. Superserver always load only ONE CPU or core. And Classic use one process per client connection. So OS will distribute processes among available CPUs.

BTW. "spasiba" sounds like "dziakuj" in belarusian ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the superserver in nearly every case. Although the superserver runs on "only" one CPU core, it's mostly faster. The reason for this is the DB server load. **It's not rendering videos or calculating wheater information. It has an extreme high IO load.** That means it reads and writes data from the memory and drives. The classic and superclassic server creates cache for every connection. That means that 10 different connections (for instance 10 client computers) will have their own cache. Let's say they are working with the same data (customers, oders...). The problem is that each connection does not have the relevant information in the cache. So every connection will load these records from the hard drive. This behavior causes an extrem high drive load and slows down everything. The superserver (version < FB 3.0) is just using one CPU core, but has one cache. So user 2,3..10 doesn't have to load the data from the drive because user 1 already loaded it into the server cache. **Taking all pieces together the superserver is faster.** And I'm looking forward to installing the firebird 3.0 release because the firebird 3.0 superserver uses multiple CPUs and has one "shared" server cache.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use script for `isql` from https://ib-aid.com/en/articles/how-to-determine-firebird-architecture-with-sql-query/ :

```html
​set list on;

set term ^;
--create or alter procedure sys_get_fb_arch (
--     a_connect_with_usr varchar(31) default 'SYSDBA'
--    ,a_connect_with_pwd varchar(31) default 'masterkey'
--) returns(
--    fb_arch varchar(50)
--) as

execute block returns( fb_arch varchar(50) )
as
    declare a_connect_with_usr varchar(31) default 'SYSDBA';
    declare a_connect_with_pwd varchar(31) default 'masterkey';
    declare cur_server_pid int;
    declare ext_server_pid int;
    declare att_protocol varchar(255);
    declare v_test_sttm varchar(255);
    declare v_fetches_beg bigint;
    declare v_fetches_end bigint;
begin
    
    -- Aux SP for detect FB architecture.
 
    select a.mon$server_pid, a.mon$remote_protocol
    from mon$attachments a
    where a.mon$attachment_id = current_connection
    into cur_server_pid, att_protocol;
 
    if ( att_protocol is null ) then
        fb_arch = 'Embedded';
    else if ( upper(current_user) = upper('SYSDBA')
              and rdb$get_context('SYSTEM','ENGINE_VERSION') NOT starting with '2.5'
              and exists(select * from mon$attachments a
                         where a.mon$remote_protocol is null
                               and upper(a.mon$user) in ( upper('Cache Writer'), upper('Garbage Collector'))
                        )
            ) then
        fb_arch = 'SuperServer';
    else
        begin
            v_test_sttm =
                'select a.mon$server_pid + 0*(select 1 from rdb$database)'
                ||' from mon$attachments a '
                ||' where a.mon$attachment_id = current_connection';
 
            select i.mon$page_fetches
            from mon$io_stats i
            where i.mon$stat_group = 0  -- db_level
            into v_fetches_beg;
        
            execute statement v_test_sttm
            on external
                 'localhost:' || rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'DB_NAME')
            as
                 user a_connect_with_usr
                 password a_connect_with_pwd
                 role left('R' || replace(uuid_to_char(gen_uuid()),'-',''),31)
            into ext_server_pid;
        
            in autonomous transaction do
            select i.mon$page_fetches
            from mon$io_stats i
            where i.mon$stat_group = 0  -- db_level
            into v_fetches_end;
        
            fb_arch = iif( cur_server_pid is distinct from ext_server_pid,
                           'Classic',
                           iif( v_fetches_beg is not distinct from v_fetches_end,
                                'SuperClassic',
                                'SuperServer'
                              )
                         );
        end
 
    fb_arch = trim(fb_arch) || ' ' || rdb$get_context('SYSTEM','ENGINE_VERSION');
 
    suspend;
 
end
 
^ -- sys_get_fb_arch
set term ;^
```